# I would like to replicate the functionality of Google Calendar, where I can display a list of interviews on a calendar

Tags: reactjs, antd

The provided code creates a calendar and retrieves a list of interviews from an API. However, it doesn't currently handle matching each interview to a specific date on the calendar. The objective is to visualize the scheduled interviews, including the interview time and candidate name, in a convenient manner. To achieve this functionality, i need to iterate through the interview list and associate each interview with its corresponding date on the calendar. but HOW  ??

````
import { Calendar } from "antd";
import { ODCLayout } from "../../../layout";
import "./styles.scss";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";

export const CalendarEntretiens = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [listEntretiens, setListEntretiens] = useState([]);

  const user = localStorage.getItem("user");
  const userData = JSON.parse(user);

  const getAllEntretiens = () => {
    setLoading(true);

    axios
      .get(`/recruter/${userData.id}/interviews/getAll`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setListEntretiens(data.interviews);
        console.log(data.interviews);
      })
      .catch(() => setLoading(false));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllEntretiens();
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <ODCLayout itemsBreadcrump={["Calendrier des entretiens"]}>
      <div className="container-calendar-entretiens">
        <Calendar/>
        <div className="tip">
          <div className="tip--color" />
          <span className="tip--name">Date réservée pour entretien</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ODCLayout>
  );
}; ```
````